# Vertical column result to horizontal

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, pivot, max

I need put a column result in to horizontal position, like `SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'On Hold' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'word'` do, I tried a subquery and alias AS too but I didn't have had success. I think that JOIN is to multiple tables, and UNION to get results in same column.

I'm using this page as reference

https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-case-function/

**mysql Table:** phpvms_pireps

`pilotid|flightnum|submitdate|accepted`

**My sql code:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT `phpvms_pireps`.`pilotid`
     , `phpvms_pireps`.`accepted`
     , `phpvms_pireps`.`flightnum`
     , `phpvms_pireps`.`submitdate`
  FROM phpvms_pireps
 WHERE ((`phpvms_pireps`.`flightnum` in ('A-1', 'A-2', 'A-3', 'A-4')))
   AND submitdate BETWEEN '2020-04-09' AND '2020-04-11'
 ORDER 
    BY `phpvms_pireps`.`pilotid` ASC
```

**The result:**

[image]

[image: check and cross is set with if accepted = 1 check, 2 cross, else don't show]

**And I want to achieve this:**

[image: edited with paint]

I'm using php/html, How I can get that result?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Comment: Hi @Strawberry what do you mean?

Comment: I mean the opposite of what GMB is suggesting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are describing a pivot table. Consider using conditional aggregation:

```
select 
    pilotid, 
    max(case when flightnum = 'A-1' then accepted end) a1,
    max(case when flightnum = 'A-2' then accepted end) a2,
    max(case when flightnum = 'A-3' then accepted end) a3,
    max(case when flightnum = 'A-4' then accepted end) a4
from phpvms_pireps 
where 
    flightnum in ('A-1', 'A-2', 'A-3', 'A-4')
    and submitdate between '2020-04-09' and '2020-04-11'
group by pilotid
order by pilotid
```

Comment: Thanks @GMB I delete the "," after a4 bacause a error:
"1 errors were found during the analysis. An expression was expected. (near "from" at position 264)"

What do "max" here exactly?

Comment: @arv187: we want one record per pilot so we `group by pilotid`. We need an aggregate function around the `case` expression, even though there is only one row that matches the condition. We could as well use `min()`, the result would be the same.